# FireSharp CreateUser(Email, Password) 500 internal error

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, fire-sharp

I am trying to create a new user using .net 5 project.

In order to communicate with firebase you need to create a client, which I am able to do with no problem and I am able to Push and Pull data to the database. However when I  am trying to create a new user using **client.CreateUser(Email, Password)**; I am getting the following error.

I did activate Email/Password auth method in the Firebase.

[Link for Firebase source code](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/blob/d1c6e23b4c35825036e9f09b24b12c84fec10f3e/FireSharp.Core/FirebaseClient.cs#L313)

The Error I am getting:

```
>     System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond. (auth.firebase.com:443))
>      ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond. (auth.firebase.com:443)
>      ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond.
>        at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16
> token)
>        at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext
> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>        at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean
> emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```